# Are begin(container) and end(container) standardized?

Tags: c++, iterator, c++11, containers, non-member-functions

Are the non-member function templates `begin(container)` and `end(container)` part of C++0x? If so, in which header file do they live?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, but just as `swap` is defined in different places and depends on ADL, so are `begin` and `end`. The 'generic' versions are defined in `<iterator>`:

```
// 24.6.5, range access:
template <class C> auto begin(C& c) -> decltype(c.begin());
template <class C> auto begin(const C& c) -> decltype(c.begin());
template <class C> auto end(C& c) -> decltype(c.end());
template <class C> auto end(const C& c) -> decltype(c.end());
template <class T, size_t N> T* begin(T (&array)[N]);
template <class T, size_t N> T* end(T (&array)[N]);
```

Note also that 24.6.5 says:

> In addition to being available via inclusion of the `<iterator>` header, the function templates in 24.6.5 are available when any of the following headers are included: `<array>`, `<deque>`, `<forward_list>`, `<list>`, `<map>`, `<regex>`, `<set>`, `<string>`, `<unordered_map>`, `<unordered_set>`, and `<vector>`.

Comment: Out of sheer curiosity: Why would someone use them instead of `c.begin()`?

Comment: @Karl because that's not possible for all types you can iterate over. That if `c` is an array.

Comment: @Karl: although the prefix syntax becomes unreadable when chained (`f(g(h(x)), a(b(y)))`), it's extensible and looks much more like functional programming. It only remains to add open multi-methods to the language.

Comment: @Karl: Atop of what Johannes and ybungalobill said: Every C++ programmer (especially those coming from Java, C# and the like) should have read [this classic article](http://drdobbs.com/184401197) by Scott Meyers.

Comment: @Karl: For a situation where global begin/end are indispensable, see the [pretty printer](http://louisdx.github.com/cxx-prettyprint/), or [STL #6](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Advanced-STL-6-of-n) (from where I got the idea).